# How do you redirect a Google Apps for Business domain to another website?

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, web-development, domain-forwarding

I have a web address (www.example.com) which I bought through Google Apps for Business.  Currently the web address shows "page not found".

I want to forward it to another external site such that when I visit the above URL it, goes to othersite.example.com.  How do I do that?

Comment: Most hosting companies have a way to redirect a domain.     I'm not familiar enough with Google Apps for Business to know how to do it there specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Find something like "Web Address Mapping" in the available options inside your admin panel. There, it should give you an option to redirect to redirect domain A (current) to domain B (interested or target domain/url/uri).

I'm not expecting it to be difficult.

It might have a different name but it should give a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have bought domain through `google` while setting up `google apps`? Try to find "Web Address Mapping" as @Avineshwar has suggested or try to find "`Sub Domains`" in your google apps account, or get me the domain name so that i can investigate.